# how can i get my text to clear when the person clicks for a new number android dice app

Tags: android

OK i have a random dice roll app and when the person picks the spinner and rolls it works but i want it were if the click it again it rerolls the number right now it wont reroll. And it stores the number if i roll a 6 sided then roll a 10 sided i get a new number but then if i go back to the 6 sided i get the original number i want it to basicly autoclear on click for a new number.

```js
package com.example.diceapp;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dice extends Activity {
 
 double random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
 double random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
 double random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
 double random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.dice);
 final Spinner group = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
 Button roll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDice);
 roll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   DecimalFormat dices = new DecimalFormat("###");
   if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("6 sided")){
    result.setText(dices.format(random));}
    else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("10 sided")){
     result.setText(dices.format(random1));}
     else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("20 sided")){
      result.setText(dices.format(random2));}
      else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("100 sided")){
       result.setText(dices.format(random3));
      }
    }
   
   
  
 });
}
}
```

That is my code please and thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the random numbers (i.e. random, random1, random2, and random3) are only calculated once because you put the calculation in the instance variable declaration. If you move those declarations into the onClick() callback as local variables, it will re-calculate the random numbers on every click. Here's the updated code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dice extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dice);
        final Spinner group = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        Button roll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDice);
        roll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            final TextView result = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult));

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                double random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
                double random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                double random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

                DecimalFormat dices = new DecimalFormat("###");
                if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("6 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random));
                } else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("10 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random1));
                } else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("20 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random2));
                } else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("100 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random3));
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can leave the random numbers as instance fields, and just recalculate them on every onClick() callback, as such:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dice extends Activity {

    double random;
    double random1;
    double random2;
    double random3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dice);
        final Spinner group = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        Button roll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDice);
        roll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            final TextView result = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult));

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
                random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

                DecimalFormat dices = new DecimalFormat("###");
                if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("6 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random));
                } else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("10 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random1));
                } else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("20 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random2));
                } else if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("100 sided")) {
                    result.setText(dices.format(random3));
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```